# IBM CDC replication to Azure Event Hub

Tags: azure, cloud, database-replication, cdc, transactional-replication

My project is trying to set up an event stream from on-premise IBM DB2 on z/OS to Azure Event Hubs on Microsoft Azure cloud services. Any inserts, updates and deletes on the DB2 database is to be captured real time and replicated over to Event Hubs for further consumption by other services down the line. While there is documentation of IBM Infosphere CDC Replication Engine for Kafka, I couldn't find any relevant literature on replication to Azure Event Hubs. Is a replication pathway from IBM Infosphere CDC to Azure Event Hubs available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a developer with the IBM Data Replication team.

Had a quick glance at Azure Event Hubs and it seems to be a managed Kafka service. Unfortunately, we don't give specific instructions on all the various distributions of Kafka as they should document what Kafka clients need to do in order to connect.

For example, a given Kafka cluster will specify the Kafka client parameters needed for authentication and authorization. We have documented how to set these required parameters in the following places:

- Installation and Configuration Guide by Frank Ketelaars (https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/files/basic/anonymous/api/library/81dc842e-307f-486b-903a-71013bb159c0/document/6e39fdce-b6d0-4865-a4f0-345386a9783d/media)
- The SSL Configuration Guide
- IBM Knowledge Center

The IBM Data Replication product uses Kafka 1.1.1 client and exposes a Kafka client property file.

Comment: Azure Event Hubs is a publisher-subscriber message streaming service like Kafka, but you are right that it can mimic Kafka. Thank you, we'll try this out.

Answer (score 0):

The commercial product "Replicate" by Attunity (now a division of Qlik), can do this with ease.

Good luck,
Hein (retired Attunity consultant)